# External monitor not detected on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, xorg, display-resolution, selinux

My external monitor is not detected by Ubuntu 18.04 My computer is an Lenovo  ideapad 330.

Yesterday it was working normaly and today when I startup my laptop it does work anymore.
It does not appear on "**Setting -> Device**" (image bellow).

I tested using another monitor with another cable and that does not work either.

**How can I setup it again?**

[Settings -> Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrXrM.png)

Xrandr output:

````
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      59.97*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32 ```
````